# private or public strings on android DB schema?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

whats the best form to declare this strings in a data base schema for android?

```
 private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
```

or

```
 public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
```

Comment: IF you will going to use `KEY_ID` in same class scope than `private` only.

Comment: Public methods, good (as long as they expose functionality of a class to consumers), public fields, bad (in nearly all situations).  The only class that should have any knowledge of `KEY_ID` is your database class.  Therefore, it should be private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always prefer to use the `private` access modifier, which is the safest practice. Unless you have to use this variables somewhere else, then change it accordingly.